# Spring MVC : How to populate my Object with JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have an update method (AJAX service) that expect an object. This object is populate by JSon and I want to test it but I can't..

I use spring mvc to set up my service.

My Service :

```
    @RequestMapping(value="texte/updateMyObject", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public void updateMyObject(MyObject myObject) throws IOException {

        logger.info("UPDATE !!!");

    }
```

My Object :

```
public class MyObject {
private Integer id;
private String name;

public MyObject(){}

// getter & setter

}
```

I use Postman (chrome tool) to test my service : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

I think I have to send the good JSON but I don't know which one.

For the moment I have test this pattern :

```
"MyObject" : {"id" : "1", "name" : "test"}
```

or 
    {"id" : "1", "name" : "test"}

**Edit 1 :**

When my service is call, the fields of myObject are all null.

**Edit 2 :**

I play this kind of HTTP request :

```
POST /myapp/texte/updateMyObject.sp HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"id" : "1", "name" : "test"}
```

**Edit 3 :**

My config spring in my web.xml. If you need my context ask me.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:spring/applicationContext-springmvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.sp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Edit 4 :** 
I made the following test to show you that my Object is not populated.

[image]

Comment: _But it doesn't work._ That statement is completely useless. Tell us _how_ it doesn't work. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: What doesn't work? `{"id" : "1", "name" : "test"}` looks apt.

Comment: these are my JSON tests not working.

Comment: To be specific. What do you see in your "updateMyObject" method. is myObject null? Is it something else? Also, is "texte" a typo?

Comment: Sorry but english are not my mother tongue so I try to be as clear as possible. If you need more details, ask me.

Comment: Do you see an error message? If so, what?

Comment: No error message. My service is called correctly and I have a code 200 in the HTTP response.

Comment: why .sp in `updateMyObject.sp`?

Comment: sp for spring request cause I map other kind of request like struts action request.

Comment: You are missing @RequestBody for MyObject parameter in your controller.

Comment: @udalmik When I put @ RequestBody I have an 415 error.

Comment: Did you link any JSON parser/formatter library such as Jackson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link a JSON de/serializer library to your project, e.g. Jackson:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, using the following controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "texte/updateMyObject", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void updateMyObject(@RequestBody MyObject myObject) {
    // ...
}
```

When sending a request such as:

```
POST /texte/updateMyObject
    headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
    data:
        { "id" : "1", "name" : "test" }
```

`myObject` shall be filled.

Comment: Yes ! With requestBody it works now cause I made another test but I don't understand why my first test don't work. I will look why ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the name of the attributes inside the JSON document your controller will receive.

On your action parameters, the type of the parameter must have attributes which will match with the name of the fields on the JSON document it will receive.

For example: take a look at this action:

```
@RequestMapping(value="texte/updateMyObject", method=RequestMethod.POST)
String doSomething(Person person) {

}
```

The person class will look like this:

```
class Person {
   String name;
   int age;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Your JSON document must be something like this:

> {'name':'Henrique', 'age':35}

Comment: I have to send all the fields in my class? If I want only send name, how do I build my JSON ?

Comment: On this case all you have to send is a JSON document with only one field: name.

Comment: I edit my post with my test. I did the same test but it doesn't work for me. See Edit 4.